# Would it be plausible for a group of pseudo-spiders to form a colony?

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, fauna

So, ants and bees form colonies, could my spider analogs from colonies? They’re the dominant species on the planet they live in, like humans are. The pseudo-spiders are about 2-3m long, about 1m tall and about 1m wide. They require about 3000 calories a day to function. The spider analogs are sexually dimorphic, with females having a larger abdomin and males having a slightly larger appearance.

Comment: Yes. And no. It all depends of the setup, and what you mean by colonies }i{. Right now we only know they're spiders or spider-like creatures and they are the dominant species (a quite blurry term, if I dare say so). We need much more to answer :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have discovered one species of [eusocial spider](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_spider) already. Having a colonial spider in your fictional world is a definite possibility.

Comment: Please add the relevant info in the answer. Should that link be dead one day, the answer would lose its value.

Comment: We have also discovered a herbivorous one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagheera_kiplingi

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, that piece of information has helped me greatly.